# Ubuntu 22.04.1 WiFi connection no longer available after previously working fine

Tags: drivers, wireless, 22.04, realtek

My laptop's (Asus ROG Zephyrus G502DA) WiFi was working just fine, then after a reboot it has disappeared and no longer gives me the ability to even search for nearby networks.

sudo lshw -class network

shows [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kSfG5.jpg)

And if I go into "Software and Updates" it shows the WiFi adapter and it's using;

DKMS source for the Realtek 8821C PCIe Wi-Fi driver from rtl8821ce-dkms (open source)

Edit: I have tried the method mentioned in the linked question;

'''
sudo apt purge rtl8821ce-dkms
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependancy tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Package 'rtl8821ce-dkms' is not installed, so not removed
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 18 not upgraded.
'''

Comment: Remove the dkms by "Don't use"

Comment: @Pilot6 Unfortunately, that didn't help, it still shows as the only driver option and it won't reinstall because I don't have an internet connection. What would be a good next step?

Comment: If you have the 5.19 kernel now, you don't need a driver. Check if the kernel module is blacklisted. You need to remove the dkms completely and make sure the in-tree module loads.

Comment: What do I need to type in to check that?

Comment: Did you read the duplicate link?

Comment: Add output of `grep rtw88_8821ce /etc/modprobe.d/*`

Comment: Sorry mate, it's not doing anything. I had to dig out an ethernet cable and now I'm plugged in on the problematic machine so at least I can copy/paste now instead of having to transcribe on my phone.

Comment: Can I roll back to what it was before? jfc I installed ubuntu a couple of weeks ago and I feel like I need to have a degree in computer science or something to do anything. It wouldn't be so frustrating if I had the time to just sit at a computer for 8 hours a day, like, there has to be a better way. I'm probably gonna nuke my whole install because it honestly seems easier

Comment: You can boot with a previous 5.15 kernel and install the dkms driver.